# Optimize Excel VBA code and define additional conditions

Tags: vba, optimization

I have a code which clears a value, if its greater than the range average + standard deviation.

Need to include a another condition that checks whether the row value is 'Correct' or Incorrect

For example If Abs(checker.Value) > Abs(SpikeValue) and cell value (for the row) is 'Correct' then checker.Clear.

Also, need to enhance the code to check for all worksheets not just 'Sheet1'

I got a 400 error (not sure why)

Sub Clear_Click()

```
Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range, checker As Range
Dim SpikeValue As Double
Dim colCount As Long, counter As Long

Set wsOut = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:AO1146")
'Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:E9")

colCount = myRange.Columns.Count
```

With wsOut
    For counter = 1 To colCount

'        SpikeValue = WorksheetFunction.Average(myRange.Columns(counter)) + WorksheetFunction.StDev(myRange.Columns(counter))
        SpikeValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myRange.Columns(counter)) + 2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(myRange.Columns(counter))

```
    For Each checker In myRange
        If Abs(checker.Value) > Abs(SpikeValue) Then checker.Clear
    Next checker
Next counter
```

End With

End Sub

Data
Name,Flag,Score1,Score2,Score3
ABC,Correct,14,7,3
DEF,Incorrect,15,8,3
GET,Correct,17,3,3
NED,Correct,18,4,9
JOB,Incorrect,14,15,2
HAL,Incorrect,15,5,2
SAL,Incorrect,17,3,3
YAY,Correct,18,3,3

If Flag = Incorrect and Cell value (Score1) > Average+Stdev of Score1, then clear the value, else check next value

Answer (score 0):

```
Something like this i guess



type check
Flag
checker_value
spike_value 
Cell_value 
Score1 
Average 
Stdevas 
end type

Sub forEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call yourfunctionforthesheet(ws)
Next
End Sub

For Each checker In myRange
 dim chk as check
 chk.checker_value=checker.value
 chk.spike_value=abs(spike_value)

 chk.flag=flag
 chk.Cell_value=cell_value
 chk.Score1= 
   ' ... and so on just fill the structure

if checkme(chk) then checker.clear

Next checker()

function checkme(chk as check ) as boolean
dim bool as boolean
bool=false
'just make bool true if the condition will clear the checker do not make her false 
'again!
if chk.checker_Value) > chk.SpikeValue Then bool = true
If chk.Flag = chk.Incorrect and chk.Cell_value (Score1) > chk.Average+chk.Stdev then 
 bool=true
checkme=bool
end function
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll try this out

Comment: UPS i made a bug :) "dim chk as checker" should be  "dim chk as check" i update the post :)